# When IngestionFailureInfo.ShouldRetry is true

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm implementing retry for failed ingest operation on ADX, my question is in the title.

On the side note, I saw some differences between `IngestionStatus` (getting ingest status via table) and `IngestionFailureInfo` (getting ingest status via queue)

- `IngestionStatus` have `Status.PartiallySucceeded`, while
  `IngestionFailureInfo` have no way to tell whether an ingest
  operation is partially succeeded or not.
- Can `Status.PartiallySucceeded` occur when ingesting from stream
  ?     How can I know if an ingest operation is
  `PartiallySucceeded`    using `IngestionFailureInfo` ?

Answer (score 1):

First note that the report to table and queue is done per blob and therefore there is no partial success for a single blob. If a report method of kind `Table` was used and the ingest is done from a `DataReader` the call to `GetIngestionStatusBySourceId` will aggregate the results of the `DataReader` ingest and therefore can get a `PartiallySucceeded` value. So for your question you can't get a `PartiallySucceeded` value when ingesting from a stream `IngestionFailureInfo` is configured only for failed operations.
In anyway `IKustoIngestionResult` methods are only relevant for checking a status in an Azure Table, for `Queue` report method see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-client-reference#interface-ikustoqueuedingestclient