# Ingest from storage with persistDetails = true not save ingest status result

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm now implement a program to migrate large amount of data to ADX base on `Ingest from Storage` feature of ADX and I'm need to check that status of each ingestion request each time the request finish but I'm facing an issue

Base on MS document in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-ingestion/#ingestion-properties)

If I set the `persistDetails = true` for example with the command below it **must** save the ingestion status but currently this setting seem not work (with or without it)

```
.ingest async into table MigrateTable
(
h'correct blob url link'
)
with (
jsonMappingReference = 'table_mapping',
format = 'json',
persistDetails = true
)
```

Above command will return an `OperationId` and when I using it to check export status when the ingest task finish I always get this error message :

`Error An admin command cannot be executed due to an invalid state: State='Operation 'DataIngestPull' does not persist its operation results' clientRequestId: KustoWebV2;`

Can someone clarify for me what is the root cause relate to this? With me it seem like a bug relate to ADX

Answer (score 1):

1. Ingesting data directly against the Data Engine, by running `.ingest` commands, is usually not recommended, compared to using [Queued Ingestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-ingest#ingest-client-flavors) (motivation included in the link). Using Kusto's [ingestion client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-ingest) allows you to track the [ingestion status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-client-status).
2. Some tools/services already do that for you, and you can consider using them directly. e.g. [LightIngest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/lightingest), [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/azure-data-factory)
3. If you don't follow option 1, you can still look for the state/status of your command using the operation ID you get when using the `async` keyword, by using [.show operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/operations)
4. You can also use the [client request ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/request-properties#the-clientrequestid-x-ms-client-request-id-named-property) to filter the result set of [.show commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/commands) to view the state/status of your command.
5. If you're interested in looking specifically at failures, [.show ingestion failures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/ingestionfailures) is also available for you.
6. The `persistDetails` option you specified in your `.ingest` command actually has no effect - as mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/operations#show-operation-details):

> Not all control commands persist their results, and those that do usually do so by default on asynchronous executions only (using the async keyword). Please search the documentation for the specific command and check if it does (see, for example data export).

Comment: Hi Yoni
I also want to know if queued ingestion is guaranteed not to have PartiallySucceeded status since it hard to trace which ingest failed. According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58518725/when-ingestionfailureinfo-shouldretry-is-true "report to table and queue is done per blob and therefore there is no partial success for a single blob", but when I used .ingest command to ingest a single blob into ADX I got PartiallySucceeded status and only half of the blob content is ingest into ADX

Comment: Which will be disaster in my case, while I try to migrate a large amount of customer data

Answer (score -1):

============ Update sample code follow suggestion from Yoni ========

Turn out, other member in my team mess up with access right with adx, after fixing it everything work fine
I just have one concern relate to `PartiallySucceeded` that need clarify from @yoni or someone have better knowledge relate to that

```
try
{
    var ingestProps = new KustoQueuedIngestionProperties(model.DatabaseName, model.IngestTableName)
    {
        ReportLevel = IngestionReportLevel.FailuresAndSuccesses,
        ReportMethod = IngestionReportMethod.Table,
        FlushImmediately = true,
        JSONMappingReference = model.IngestMappingName,
        AdditionalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"jsonMappingReference",$"{model.IngestMappingName}" },
            { "format","json"}
        }
    };

    var sourceId = Guid.NewGuid();
    var clientResult = await IngestClient.IngestFromStorageAsync(model.FileBlobUrl, ingestProps, new StorageSourceOptions
    {
        DeleteSourceOnSuccess = true,
        SourceId = sourceId
    });

    var ingestionStatus = clientResult.GetIngestionStatusBySourceId(sourceId);
    while (ingestionStatus.Status == Status.Pending)
    {
        await Task.Delay(WaitingInterval);
        ingestionStatus = clientResult.GetIngestionStatusBySourceId(sourceId);
    }

    if (ingestionStatus.Status == Status.Succeeded)
    {
        return true;
    }

    LogUtils.TraceError(_logger, $"Error when ingest blob file events, error: {ingestionStatus.ErrorCode.FastGetDescription()}");
    return false;
}
catch (Exception e)
{    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it's not clear (to me) what is the standing question you require an answer to - could you please clarify that? alongside providing more information about a specific case/operations in the past you're referring to, if you are

Comment: Oh sorry for make you feel confuse, my question that I need to ask you is in comment section of your previous answer. I will post it again in here to easy to see

Comment: Hi Yoni I also want to know if queued ingestion is guaranteed not to have PartiallySucceeded status since it hard to trace which ingest failed. According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58518725/when-ingestionfailureinfo-shouldretry-is-true 

"report to table and queue is done per blob and therefore there is no partial success for a single blob", but when I used .ingest command to ingest a single blob into ADX I got PartiallySucceeded status and only half of the blob content is ingest into ADX

Comment: a single valid blob is either fully ingested of fully fails - if you've seen a different case, i'd recommend opening a support ticket for your resource through the Azure portal

Comment: I do see a case like that when I try to ingest large amount of data via `ingest into table ` command

At that time I try to ingest 2 blob files with each file have size around 1gb and get `Partially success` status return. When I check the record at that point I saw it miss some few records. That is why I wonder, Does `Queue ingestion` and  ingest via `ingest from table` command implement differently behind the scene ?

Comment: No, the underlying implementation of the ingestion part itself is identical. As previously mentioned, you can look at the reason for partial success using ".show ingestion failures". If you require assistance with investigating the failure, once again, I'd strongly recommend you open a support ticket, as it impossible to guess the reason in this forum without additional data points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203336/discussion-between-yoni-l-and-tung-thai).